# Why is the text not lining up?

Tags: formatting, text, center

So I have this problem where the centered text will not line up together and I want to fix it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\author{Đào Mộng Nam}
\title{Chữ Nho tự học}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Kết}
    \noindent
    Ngày xưa bàn về truyện Kiều học giả Phạm Quỳnh có viết:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            Truyện Kiều còn, tiếng ta còn, \\
            tiếng ta còn, nước ta còn           
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    Hôm nay để thay cho lời kết của bài này chúng tôi xin thêm:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            Chữ Nho còn thì truyện Kiều còn, \\
            truyện Kiều còn thì tinh thần \\
            truyền thống của chúng ta còn, \\
            tinh thần truyền thống của \\
            chúng ta còn thì nước ta còn.
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Sài thành, mùa thu tháng 9, 1966 \\
        ĐÀO MỘNG NAM
        \end{tabular}
    \end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example that others can copy as is. Here the document class and relevant preamble is missing.

Comment: I have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `tabular*` environment, with two dummy columns so the middle one is actually centered and interrupt it for the paragraph in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\interrupt}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \vbox{%
      \let\par\@@par
      \leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
      \vspace{\topsep}#1\par\vspace{\topsep}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection{Kết}

Ngày xưa bàn về truyện Kiều học giả Phạm Quỳnh có viết:
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}clc}
& Truyện Kiều còn, tiếng ta còn, & \\
& tiếng ta còn, nước ta còn      & \\
\interrupt{Hôm nay để thay cho lời kết của bài này chúng tôi xin thêm:}
& Chữ Nho còn thì truyện Kiều còn, & \\
& truyện Kiều còn thì tinh thần & \\
& truyền thống của chúng ta còn, & \\
& tinh thần truyền thống của & \\
& chúng ta còn thì nước ta còn. & \\
\interrupt{\hspace*{\fill}\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Sài thành, mùa thu tháng 9, 1966 \\
  ĐÀO MỘNG NAM
  \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]